# noob, but I installed python 2.7.5 on my mac, how to I "target" that one rather than the built in 2.7.2?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I went thought and installed `pip` and then added a bunch of libraries that I like to use and then, only after installing everything, did I realize that everything went into the 2.7.2 sit-packages directory, so the Python2.7.5 version doesn't see anything.

Now, If I type `python --version` in the terminal, the correct version is started. However, `pip` is still "tied" to the default version of Python.

How do I go about telling OSX to look at the new version of Python for everything?

Comment: If you can, you should use virtualenv to accomplish what you want. There is a very good tutorial here: http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, one way around this is to make sure that `virtualenv` works with the right version, and just use pip inside the virtualenv.

Comment: Ah, that worked! I had to explicitly tell the virtualenv the Python version I wanted with the `-p` flag and a path to the 2.7.5 build. Should be smooth sailing now! Thanks!

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro Excellent! You'll want to keep one "messing around" virtualenv, and maybe create a source script (i.e. one you source rather than execute) to get up and running in there conveniently when you just want to try things out.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern of Python installation on the mac is to use [Home Brew](http://brew.sh/) which is a package manager for the mac. You can then install python using:

```
sudo brew update
brew install python
```

Provided you have the XCode command line tools already installed.
After I think that the Home Brew Python will be the first in the path. If this is not the case, it might be simpler to use a virtualenv by installing the package with the pip provided by the Mac Brew install (`/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/bin/pip`).
After this is done you need to create a virtualenv

```
virtualenv ~/path/to/the/env
```

and to activate it

```
source ~/path/to/the/env/bin/activate
```

This will be a brand new python and your path will be configured correctly (the python and the pip will be the right ones). You can always delete it, `deactivate` it or `source` it as needed.